# Why is the time complexity of merge intervals algorithm O(n log n) and not O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity, complexity-theory

In a merge intervals algorithm, we first sort the intervals, which is O(log n), and then iterate through them to perform the merge, which is O(n).

I have seen it stated that this makes the merge intervals algorithm O(n log n). But from what I can see, since we only perform the sort once, and then afterwards we iterate once over the intervals, we should have complexity O(log n) + O(n) = O(n).

So what I am missing? Why are O(log n) and O(n) multiplied together instead of added when computing the complexity?

```
def merge(intervals):
  if len(intervals) < 2:
    return intervals

  intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)

  mergedIntervals = []
  start = intervals[0].start
  end = intervals[0].end
  for i in range(1, len(intervals)):
    interval = intervals[i]
    if interval.start <= end:
      end = max(interval.end, end)
    else:
      mergedIntervals.append(Interval(start, end))
      start = interval.start
      end = interval.end

  # add the last interval
  mergedIntervals.append(Interval(start, end))
  return mergedIntervals
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you think sorting is `O(log n)`. Sorting is typically implemented in `O(n log n)` or worse ([see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/)).

The rest of the calculation is correct: `O(nlog n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`.